# change <finalName> file extension apache-shade-plugin

Tags: java, maven, build

I'm using the shade plugin to create a fat jar. The packaging type is pom and there is no code in this project. The problem is that the generated jar file has an extension .pom. How can I fix that? I already tried with `<finalName>` but the file-extension is generated automatically. When I change the packaging type to jar, the build process hangs on:

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ fat-jar ---
[INFO] Deleting /a/home/Projects/project/headless/fat-jar/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ fat-jar ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
```

Comment: What do you mean by `hangs on..`...a pom file would also be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to attach the fat jar as additional output with the build helper plugin or something along these lines. It should however also work with packaging jar to produce the light one and then as additional one for the fat jar.

We would need more code snippets to tell you more. Or an example project.